# create a local(my computer only) package

Tags: node.js

I have two projects, one called "core" and other called "tagger" and I want to use core as a module of tagger.

I tried to install "core" globally `npm install . -g` but when I `require("core")` in tagger, it does not work.

When I install it, a folder called "core" is created in `C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` with a package.json(`name = "core"`) and my index.js.

When I try to require it, I receive an error `Error: Cannot find module 'core'`

So, how can I package one project to use in another without publishing it to npm?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia). Pretty easy to set up (even in Windows) and it allows you to publish and use private npm packages. This is the cleanest approach.

If you really don't want to install a local repository, you can also specify the path of "core" in your dependencies in the package.json for your "tagger" project. More details can be found under "local paths" in [the package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Answer (score 1):

You can try different [npm install methods](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), ex. `npm install <git remote url>`, etc.